# Why doesn't dm-crypt handle write barriers properly?

Tags: hard-disk, cache, dm-crypt

One of the well-known properties of `dm-crypt` is that it does not handle write barriers properly and hence it requires turning off on-drive write cache to prevent corruption of filesystems. As far as I understand it is not shared by all other dm devices (like LVM w/out snapshoting).

My question is whether it is an inherent property of `dm-crypt` for any reason (I cannot find any but it is possible) or is it simply not implemented (yet)?

Comment: In the past, almost none of LVM / DM code contained support for write barriers, but now it is a work in progress. I can't think of any reason why dm-crypt should not support it, so you can check if it has been added in the newest version or maybe ask on the lvm-devel mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

See that answer to related question: https://serverfault.com/a/382515/67675